# Bootstrap Login page gets broken on some screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a demo page with bootstrap but on some sizes it acts weird. Probably I am missing some key aspects of bootstrap, or maybe its a bug :) Can you give me some advice here?
The problem seems to caused by the form / field itself. Tried to add some spans etc but did not work either. The layout gets worse in 1024x768 :D The input fields gets off the container.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1 class="text-center">Welcome</h1></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span4 offset4 well">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Please login</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">User name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" class="input-xlarge" required type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="input-xlarge" required type="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="giris" name="giris" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <p class="muted">This is a demo login page <a class="text-error" href="#">click here</a> for more info.</p>
    </div>
   </div>


    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4 offset4 well"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> </div>
    </div>


</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem on a jsfddle for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes like  `span4` and `offset4` follow responsive layout mechanism implemented in bootstrap. My advice is to add some fixed width for your form container with auto left and right margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/6uwkL/

**CSS**

```
.form-container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1 class="text-center">Welcome</h1></div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="form-container well">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Please login</legend>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">User name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="textinput" name="textinput" class="input-xlarge" required type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="input-xlarge" required type="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <button id="giris" name="giris" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <p class="muted">This is a demo login page <a class="text-error" href="#">click here</a> for more info.</p>
    </div>
   </div>


    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="form-container well"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p> </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked this way. Nice example to learn, appreciated!